# Django - collectstatic 'ImproperlyConfigured' traceback when deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, collectstatic

I'm learning to use Django and am trying to deploy a project on Heroku. When I try to deploy the project through the command window I get the following traceback when it runs `python manage.py collectstatic`

```
Improperly Configured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set
the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

My settings for heroku are:

```
if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER  = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]

    # Static set configuration 
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATICFILES_DIR = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

I'm new to django and I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Why do you have that strange guard in your settings file? You don't need anything like that.

Comment: Extending @DanielRoseman comment, check out Heroku's starter template for Django as the recommended way to configure the project [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template/blob/master/project_name/settings.py)

Comment: @AlanAvalos Thanks I'll check that out.